# Redirecting AWS ELB HTTP Requests to HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, amazon-elb, amazon-ecs

When we use AWS Application Load Balancer to redirect incoming requests to our servers, we created an SSL certificate and set it to the load balancer. It both listens HTTP 80 and HTTPS 443 ports' traffic. In both cases, traffic is redirected to target group instances' HTTP 80 port.

In these instances, there are nginx servers which are configured to listen HTTP 80 ports of the instance they are in. (These instances are Elastic Container Service instances)

When I update the nginx.conf file to redirect incoming HTTP requests to redirect to HTTPS protocol, we are facing a redirect loop. Even if the original request is an HTTPS request, behind the load balancer, EC2 instance is listening HTTP port. So it doesn't matter if the original request is HTTP or HTTPS, nginx infinitely sends redirect.

1. I saw that Cloudfront is an option, but I'm not interested in using
   another service of AWS and paying them extra money just to overcome
   this issue.
2. Other solution might be changing HTTP listener to HTTPS inside the instances registered to target group of the ELB. Since we are using ECS, we have to find a way to secure our SSL certificate keys while creating the docker image. I don't want to put our SSL certificate inside code repository for jenkins to use it. There will be extra work if I choose this solution.

Do you have any simpler ideas to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Nginx will always get requests over HTTP, so obviously you can't tell it to redirect all HTTP requests. The ELB sets a special HTTP header on the requests it sends to your back-end servers, named `x-forwarded-proto`, that you need configure Nginx to use to check if the connection between the browser and the ELB is over HTTP or HTTPS, and only redirect if that is HTTP. I would check [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/515957/how-to-have-nginx-forward-the-http-x-forwarded-proto-header) on ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark B mentioned, checking the custom header values for the incoming prototol is the simplest way to handle this and eliminate the redirect loop.

However, if you want to ensure end-to-end encryption, you can deploy self-signed certificates in your containers.  The load balancer does NOT require a valid, public certificate in order to connect to HTTPS origin.

That way you can forward port 80 on the ALB to port 80 on the target group (and you could even have a separate target group just for redirecting) and force the redirect as you're doing now, and forward port 443 on the ALB to port 443 on the target group.